# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbc in position 20: invalid start byte

Tags: python, sockets, module

I know that there are a lot of similar posts, but none of them seem to fit my situation.

I have a code for a server that I run on my Putty SSH (Ubuntu latest version) with tmux.
All that the server is doing is receiving data from user and store it in a text folder. Code is as follows:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print("Socket Created...")

server = ''
port = 5555

s.bind((server, port))
print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))

s.listen(8)
print("Waiting for connections.")

while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected with ", addr)
    gamemodename = c.recv(1024).decode()
    #rest of code afterwards.
```

After this, I have a bunch of if statements which changes action depending on "gamemodename".
The problem that I'm getting is this occasional error:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/root/UBS-server/server.py", line 18, in  gamemodename = c.recv(1024).decode() UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbc in position 20: invalid start byte

After this error, server stops running.

I'm wondering if anyone could help me and tell me whats the problem with the code and how I could fix it.
Or at least guide me how to do it so that everytime I get this error, server can continue working or restart automatically. :)

Comment: you could try `gamemodename = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-16')`. If the encoding might vary you could use `try` and `except` with multiple encodings.

Comment: I'm not really interested in receiving anything except utf-8 though. Do you think theres any way I can make it so that whenever someone sends some other kind of information (not utf8), server will automatically ignore it and keep going? Is this kind of thing done with "try" and "except"? Sorry if I'm asking too many questions.

Comment: exactly, enclose `gamemodename = c.recv(1024).decode()` in a `try` block and do nothing (`pass` or `continue`) in the `except` block

Comment: what should I put after "except"? should I write 

except UnicodeDecodeError:
    
    continue

like this?
and one more question, should I only put "gamemodename = c.recv(1024).decode()" in a try block or everything that's after it aswell (about 300 lines)?

Comment: only put `gamemodename = c.recv(1024).decode()` in the try block and `continue` in the `except UnicodeDecodeError` block. That way you will still notice other errors and your loop will continue (ignoring the remaining 300 lines). see [continue statement](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_while_continue.asp)